# Error while accessing wcf-rest function

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, web-services

I am getting following error when i try to access the wcf-rest.

**Operation 'Login' in contract 'SelectorFront' specifies Method 'Get' on the WebGetAttribute/WebInvokeAttribute, but the only allowed values for Method are GET or POST. Other values are not supported by 'System.ServiceModel.Description.WebScriptEnablingBehavior'.**

I have created a wcf-rest, with 1 method "Login" and has one parameter "Username"
This is my function call.

**localhost:2664/FrontService.svc/Login?Username=max**

And my wcf is as following

**Interface**

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "Get", UriTemplate = "/Login/{UserName}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)] 
string Login(string UserName);
```

**Service**

```
public string Login(string UserName)
{
tblUser obj = (from m in dataContext.tblUsers
where m.UserName == UserName
select m).First();
JavaScriptSerializer oSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string sJSON = oSerializer.Serialize(obj);
return sJSON;
}
```

what is the solution of this issue

Answer (score 1):

Try using "GET" not "Get"

It's case sensitive apparently.

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET" ...
```

Comment: Yes. you are right. i tried that but i am getting another error.
"Endpoints using 'UriTemplate' cannot be used with 'System.ServiceModel.Description.WebScriptEnablingBehavior'"